# Should I take steps to ensure a Django app can scale before writing it?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, postgresql, python-3.x

So, I'm looking at writing an app with python2 django(-rest-framework), postgres and angular.

I'm aware there are lots of things that can be done

- multi-server setup behind load balancer
- DB replication/sharding?
- caching (in various ways)
- swapping DRF serialiser for serpy
- running on python3
- running on pypy

my question is - Which of these (or other things) should really be done right at the start of the project?

Comment: I am not an expert on performance, but in my experience the bottleneck of a Django application has been database access. If you know right now you are going to need scalability maybe you should consider using NoSQL?

Comment: "NoSQL" is a very vague term describing a lot of unrelated technologies, which may OR NOT help wrt/ scaling (whether vertically or horizontally), depending on the exact project. But as a general rule of thumb I would not give up a robust SQL database as the main datastore unless I have clear evidences I don't need a SQL database AND it really is a bottleneck.

Comment: This project is actually going to be a re-write of a MEAN project - where one of the bigger issues was MongoDBs lack of relational data/querys was causing *serious* problems - Cassandra and some other systems seem tempting - but Djangos ORM with fantastic query language and decent postGIS support is something I'd be rather reluctant to drop - though, willing to if it really makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write with scalability in mind.

**scaliability** is not limited just to production servers/environments but also to development environments.

Always write with scalability in mind.

### At development

Scalability at development let you develop the product seemlessly.

1. **Structure your repository** 
   Use git branching models like GitFlow so that developers can work on parallel, or a single developer can switch working on different features. Use a bug tracker.
2. **Design your apps.** 
   Before actually writing a single line of code, write down what apps you are going to write. Design apps as to minimize Relations (ManyToMany, ForeignKey, etc..), imports. Django offers pulggable app architecture feel free to use it wisely.
3. **Write your tests first.** 
   This ensures that you can migrate(production environments), upgrade and downgrade with less pain and hairloss. Trust me writing tests feels so boring, but it is worth to.
4. **Abstract models, managers** 
   Use Abstract Models and Managers, it can eliminate bolier plate model code and help you maintain the code.
5. **Name variables, classes and methods descriptive.** 
   Name the variables, classes and methods descriptive, as you would be able to know what it represents without looking documentation.
6. **Document code.** 
   Feel free to document classes and methods, so you or other peers who look into the code get an idea of what it is indented for than stacktracing to see what a method is doing.
7. **Use debug toolbar** 
   Use django debug toolbar on developement, as you test your API, use `prefectch_related()` and `select_related()` to minimize/eliminate duplicated queries.
8. **Modularize code.** 
   Modularize the code. Python and django in general encourage use of modules. Modules are easy to manage. Use classes, more inheritance and abstract base classes to reuse code.
9. **Use Continuous Integration**  
   use continuous integration test your repo and make sure new pushes don't break the system.

### At production.

scalability at production let you serve the product to infinite users seemlessly.

1. **For multi server setup**

   - Stick with rest design principles.
   - Eliminate sessions.
   - Use distributed cache like Redis.
2. **Swapping DRF serializer for serpy** 
   Start with serpy if you need more speed and if you are comfortable with. It is better to stick with Serpy than rewriting DRF serializer as writing both looks smiliar, but make sure you are not wasting time by optimizing for the lost 1 or 2ms.
3. **Running on python3** 
   Depends on the libraries that you plan to use.
4. **Running on pypy** 
   pypy is faster than the standard implementations. It depends on the library compatibility to use pypy. [A list of compatibile package and status of compatibility.](http://packages.pypy.org/)

now the question,

Which of these (or other things) should really be done right at the start of the project?

Ans: Developemet (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) Production(1,2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to start worrying about the setup right away. I would discourage premature optimizations. Rather, run the app in production, profile it. See what affects the performance when you hit scale - you would know what's the bottleneck.

Comment: This is my current plan - though I've often found some things make much more sense to do right at the start

Answer (score 1):

The first and main things you have to get right are a clean and correct db schema and clear, readable and correctly factored (DRY... unless it's accidental duplication) and decoupled code. If you know to design a relational DB schema and learn to use Python and Django properly you shouldn't have much problems so far, and if you get both these things right it will (well it should) be easy to scale - by adding cache where needed (Redis, Memcache, or an intermediary NoSQL document database storing "pre-processed" versions of your often accessed data), adding servers, load-balancing etc, depending on your application's needs. Django is built to scale easily, and unless you do stupid things it does scale easily.

Comment: Though it could be another question - any mention of what some of the bigger "stupid things" to avoid may be in this context?